# slack app channel:history scope works only in one workspace

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-commands

I have a few workspaces in my slack.
each workspace has the same app installed in it.

I'm trying to use `channel:history` scope for getting a `message` event.

the issue is that its works only in one workspace, the workspace mentioned in Your Apps list: [My Apps](https://api.slack.com/apps).
for all other workspaces there is a `scope missing` Error.

each app works only for the mentioned workspace [ass seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7r3Dl.png) .

Why is this happening?

Comment: If this is the same app installed in all workspace make sure you re-install the app. It's possible that you recently added the scope and it won't work unless you reinstall the app.

Comment: @sandra The issue was that the 'channel:history' scope was missing in the app installation options.
thanks for answering